# Proving $\cos(4\theta) - 4\cos(2\theta) \equiv 8\sin^4\theta - 3$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove the following identity:
>   $$\cos(4\theta) - 4\cos(2\theta) \equiv 8\sin^4\theta - 3$$

How can I express $\cos(4\theta) $ in other terms?

Comment: $\cos 4\theta = \cos^2 2\theta - \sin^2 2\theta = 2\cos^2 2\theta - 1 = 1 - 2\sin^2 2\theta$  and then expand again. Or. jumping to the chase $\cos 4\theta = \cos^4 \theta -6\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta + \sin^4\theta$  But, if you don't know the former, you wouldn't know the latter.

Comment: Do you mean $\equiv$ rather than $=$ when you say identity sign?

Comment: Yes, how do you do it?

Comment: @RiduanGonzalez Use "\equiv" to write the $\equiv$ symbol.

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos (4\theta)=2\cos^2 (2\theta)-1=2(1-2\sin^2 \theta)^2-1=8\sin^4 \theta-8\sin^2 \theta+1$$

$$4\cos 2\theta = 4(1-2\sin^2 \theta)=4-8\sin^2 \theta$$

> $$\cos 4\theta-4\cos 2\theta= (8\sin^4 \theta-8\sin^2 \theta+1)-(4-8\sin^2 \theta)=8\sin^4 \theta-3$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(4\theta)=2\cos^2(2\theta)-1\to\\ \cos(4\theta) - 4\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^2(2\theta)- 4\cos(2\theta)-1\to\\
\cos(4\theta) - 4\cos(2\theta)=2(1-2\sin^2(\theta))^2-4(1-2\sin^2(\theta))-1=8\sin^4(\theta)-3$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\cos(4\theta)=2\cos^2(2\theta)-1$ and $\cos(2\theta)=1-\sin^2(\theta)$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\cos(4\theta) - 4\cos(2\theta)&=2\cos^2(2\theta)- 4\cos(2\theta)-1 \\
&=2(1-2\sin^2(\theta))^2-4(1-2\sin^2(\theta))-1\\
&=2-8\sin^2(\theta)+8\sin^4(\theta)-4+8\sin^2(\theta)-1\\
&=8\sin^4(\theta)-3.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

LHS:
$$
\cos (4 \theta)-4\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^2(2\theta)-1-4\cos(2\theta)
$$
RHS:
$$
8\sin^4(\theta)-3=2\left( 2\sin^2 \theta\right)^2-3=2(1-\cos(2\theta))^2-3=2+2\cos^2(2\theta)-4\cos(2\theta)-3
$$